# Alphabetically sort array of objects based on property value php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I'm struggling to sort my array of objects into alphabetical order by the title key. Getting error that 'title' is undefined.

I want to go from this:

```
My Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [area] => TACT
            [pages] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1484
                            [title] => Registry
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1385
                            [title] => Education
```

To:

```
My Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [area] => TACT
            [pages] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1385
                            [title] => Education
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1484
                            [title] => Registry
```

Have tried:

```
function sort_alpha_title($a, $b) {
    return strnatcmp($a['title'], $b['title']);
}

usort($myArray, 'sort_alpha_title');
```

Comment: `usort($myArray[0]['pages'], 'sort_alpha_title');`?

Comment: thanks! this works. But only for one of my objects in the array. Sorry the description should of said. ive tried putting a for each loop but that's not working. here's what i tried: foreach($myArray as $a) { usort($a['pages'], 'sort_alpha_title'); }

Comment: This is not an array of objects; it is an array of arrays of arrays.  Please always offer your input array data as `var_export()` text so that contributors can instantly use your complete and valid data set in their demonstrations.  Your sample data set may be too small for us to understand your desired result.  Please slightly extend your realistic input data to better reflect its structure and explicitly declare what your exact desired result from the sample data is.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
function sort_alpha_title($a, $b) {
  return strnatcmp($a['title'], $b['title']);
}

usort($myArray[0]['pages'], 'sort_alpha_title');
```

Because the title property is a child property of the pages property.

Comment: thanks! this works. But only for one of my objects in the array. Sorry the description should of said. ive tried putting a for each loop but that's not working. here's what i tried: foreach($myArray as $a) {
   usort($a['pages'], 'sort_alpha_title');
}

Answer (score 0):

```
$myArray = array(
    array(
        'area' => 'TACT',
        'pages' => array(
            array(
                'id' => 1484,
                'title' => 'Registry'
            ),
            array(
                'id' => 1385,
                'title' => 'Education'
            )
        )
    )
);

function sort_alpha_title($a, $b)
{
    return strnatcmp($a["title"], $b["title"]);
}

usort($myArray[0]['pages'], 'sort_alpha_title');
var_dump($myArray);
```

Sry for the doubled answer but i cant add a comment because of my reputation.
tomhuckle wrote

> thanks! this works. But only for one of my objects in the array. Sorry the description should of said. ive tried putting a for each loop but that's not working. here's what i tried: foreach($myArray as $a) { usort($a['pages'], 'sort_alpha_title'); }

you dont need the foreach-loop (at the end of your comment) because its already "looped" within one call.

best regards